# nodejs, typescript store and handle websocket connections

Tags: reactjs, typescript

how can I please enter a new element in a value pair?
If a websocket has been established, I would like to save the socket connectin together with a unique userid.

```
let wsClientsList: {[key: string]: websocket.connection};

const getUniqueID = () => {
    const s4 = () => Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4();
};

const connection = request.accept(undefined, request.origin);
wsClientsList[userID] = connection; //<<< how can I add the connectionion to the list?
// get a Error       ^^^ "TypeError: Cannot set property 'e2280f5c-774c' of undefined"
```